# using Tor as Proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest, tor

I'm trying to use Tor-Server as a proxy in `HttpWebRequest`, my code looks like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request;
HttpWebResponse response;

request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:9051");

response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();
```

it works perfect with "normal" proxies but with Tor I'm getting Exceptions while calling

`GetResponse() with Status = ServerProtocolViolation. The message is (in German...):Message = "Der Server hat eine Protokollverletzung ausgeführt.. Section=ResponseStatusLine"`

Answer (score 34):

If you have [privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org/) installed and running you can do

```
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:8118"); // default privoxy port
```

Which will enable you to make requests using tor

Comment: Of course you have to edit config.txt in Privoxy folder file first and uncomment the line         `forward-socks5   /               127.0.0.1:9050 .`

Comment: Vidalia was now removed from the Tor Bundle.

Comment: I have manually downloaded and installed both the Tor Bundle and the Privoxy. I have uncomented the line mentioned on the config file and added the proxy to my webrequest object, but it gives me error 503 - server unavailable and theres no log on the privoxy indicating that the request got routed through it

Have you managed to make it work?

Comment: I am trying to change config.txt but it say's access denied?

Comment: @confusedMind Simply open your text editor as administrator, then find the config file and edit it.

Comment: I was able to change the configuration file, after opening as an admin.  However, now that I have changed these settings with Tor open, I'm receiving the same 503 error.  And Provixy startup log says "000000a0 Error: Wrong number of parameters for forward-socks4a directive in configuration file."  All my forward-socks4a are disabled.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 25):

Tor is *not* an HTTP proxy. It's a SOCKS proxy. You can use an HTTP proxy that supports forwarding on SOCKS (like Privoxy) and connect to that via code instead.

Comment: Lay: nothing is built in .NET to forward HTTP stuff via a SOCKS proxy.

Answer (score 8):

Yes like the other poster said, a socks client is needed. Some libraries are [Starksoft Proxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/starksoftproxyc/), [ProxySocket](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/class.qpx?id=9) and [ComponentSpace Socks Proxy](http://www.componentspace.com/Products/Proxy.aspx). [sockscap](http://www.your-freedom.net/index.php?id=179) is a tool that intercepts and reroutes winsock calls, and [privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org) is a local proxy that can tunnel your requests over socks. A couple different solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Use the library "SocksWebProxy". You can use it with WebClient & WebRequest (Just assign a new SocksWebProxy to the *.Proxy attribute). No Need for Privoxy or similar service to translate http traffic to tor.

https://github.com/Ogglas/SocksWebProxy

I made some extensions to it as well by enabling the control port. Here is how you could have Tor running in the background without Tor Browser Bundle started and to control Tor we can use Telnet or send commands programmatically via Socket.

```
Socket server = null;

//Authenticate using control password
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9151);
server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
server.Connect(endPoint);
server.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("AUTHENTICATE \"your_password\"" + Environment.NewLine));
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
int receivedDataLength = server.Receive(data);
string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, receivedDataLength);

//Request a new Identity
server.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("SIGNAL NEWNYM" + Environment.NewLine));
data = new byte[1024];
receivedDataLength = server.Receive(data);
stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, receivedDataLength);
if (!stringData.Contains("250"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to signal new user to server.");
    server.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    server.Close();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("SIGNAL NEWNYM sent successfully");
}
```

Steps to configure Tor:

1. Copy torrc-defaults into the directory in which tor.exe is. Default directory if you are using Tor browser is: "~\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor"
2. Open a cmd prompt window
3. chdir to the directory where tor.exe is. Default directory if you are using Tor browser is: "~\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\"
4. Generate a password for Tor control port access. `tor.exe --hash-password “your_password_without_hyphens” | more`
5. Add your password password hash to torrc-defaults under ControlPort 9151. It should look something like this: `hashedControlPassword 16:3B7DA467B1C0D550602211995AE8D9352BF942AB04110B2552324B2507`. If you accept your password to be "password" you can copy the string above.
6. You can now access Tor control via Telnet once it is started. Now the code can run, just edit the path to where your Tor files are located in the program.
   Test modifying Tor via Telnet:
7. Start tor with the following command: `tor.exe -f .\torrc-defaults`
8. Open up another cmd prompt and type: `telnet localhost 9151`
9. If all goes well you should see a completely black screen. Type "`autenticate “your_password_with_hyphens”`" If  all goes well you should see "250 OK".
10. Type "`SIGNAL NEWNYM`" and you will get a new route, ergo new IP. If  all goes well you should see "250 OK".
11. Type "`setevents circ`" (circuit events) to enable console output
12. Type "`getinfo circuit-status`" to see current circuits

Answer (score 0):

You need "extract" a stream from socks...

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Class Form1

    Sub Form1_Load() Handles Me.Load

        Dim Host As String = "google.com"

        Dim P As New SocksProxy("localhost", 64129) 'Set your socks proxy here
        Dim Stream As NetworkStream = P.GetStream(Host, 80)
        Dim buffer As Byte() = Download(Stream, Host, "")

        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes("C:\webpage.html", buffer, False)

        MsgBox("ok")
    End Sub

    Function Download(Stream As NetworkStream, Host As String, Resource As String) As Byte()

        Using writer = New StreamWriter(Stream)
            writer.Write(String.Format("GET /{2} HTTP/1.1{0}Host: {1}{0}{0}", vbCrLf, Host, Resource))
            writer.Flush()

            Dim byteList As New List(Of Byte)
            Dim bufferSize As Integer = 4096
            Dim buffer(bufferSize - 1) As Byte

            Do
                Dim bytesRead As Integer = Stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)
                byteList.AddRange(buffer.Take(bytesRead))
            Loop While Stream.DataAvailable

            Return byteList.ToArray
        End Using

    End Function
End Class


Public Class SocksProxy

    Private _SocksHost As String
    Private _SocksPort As Integer

    Sub New(SocksHost As String, SocksPort As Integer)
        _SocksHost = SocksHost
        _SocksPort = SocksPort
    End Sub

    Function GetStream(HostDest As String, PortDest As Short) As NetworkStream

        Dim client As TcpClient = New TcpClient()
        client.Connect(_SocksHost, _SocksPort)

        Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
        'Auth
        Dim buf = New Byte(299) {}
        buf(0) = &H5
        buf(1) = &H1
        buf(2) = &H0
        stream.Write(buf, 0, 3)

        ReadExactSize(stream, buf, 0, 2)
        If buf(0) <> &H5 Then
            Throw New IOException("Invalid Socks Version")
        End If
        If buf(1) = &HFF Then
            Throw New IOException("Socks Server does not support no-auth")
        End If
        If buf(1) <> &H0 Then
            Throw New Exception("Socks Server did choose bogus auth")
        End If

        buf(0) = &H5
        buf(1) = &H1
        buf(2) = &H0
        buf(3) = &H3
        Dim domain = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(HostDest)
        buf(4) = CByte(domain.Length)
        Array.Copy(domain, 0, buf, 5, domain.Length)
        Dim port = BitConverter.GetBytes(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(CShort(PortDest)))
        buf(5 + domain.Length) = port(0)
        buf(6 + domain.Length) = port(1)
        stream.Write(buf, 0, domain.Length + 7)


        ' Reply
        ReadExactSize(stream, buf, 0, 4)
        If buf(0) <> &H5 Then
            Throw New IOException("Invalid Socks Version")
        End If
        If buf(1) <> &H0 Then
            Throw New IOException(String.Format("Socks Error {0:X}", buf(1)))
        End If
        Dim rdest = String.Empty
        Select Case buf(3)
            Case &H1
                ' IPv4
                ReadExactSize(stream, buf, 0, 4)
                Dim v4 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buf, 0)
                rdest = New IPAddress(v4).ToString()
                Exit Select
            Case &H3
                ' Domain name
                ReadExactSize(stream, buf, 0, 1)
                If buf(0) = &HFF Then
                    Throw New IOException("Invalid Domain Name")
                End If
                ReadExactSize(stream, buf, 1, buf(0))
                rdest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 1, buf(0))
                Exit Select
            Case &H4
                ' IPv6
                Dim octets = New Byte(15) {}
                ReadExactSize(stream, octets, 0, 16)
                rdest = New IPAddress(octets).ToString()
                Exit Select
            Case Else
                Throw New IOException("Invalid Address type")
        End Select
        ReadExactSize(stream, buf, 0, 2)
        Dim rport = CUShort(IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(CShort(BitConverter.ToUInt16(buf, 0))))

        Return stream
    End Function

    Private Sub ReadExactSize(stream As NetworkStream, buffer As Byte(), offset As Integer, size As Integer)
        While size <> 0
            Dim read = stream.Read(buffer, offset, size)
            If read < 0 Then
                Throw New IOException("Premature end")
            End If
            size -= read
            offset += read
        End While
    End Sub

End Class
```