# Is it possible to utilize the TOR network in a .net program?

Tags: c#, privacy, tor

I have a program that utilizes a client/server approach over the Internet. I'd like to offer my customers the option to tunnel through the TOR network for complete confidentiality and protection against tracing the servers source. Is this possible? Are there any libraries for accomplishing this? Assuming its not a viable option are there any other suggestions?

references:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network)

Comment: TOR is infrastructure. If you point you application to use the TOR proxy, it will use TOR. Don't make the mistake and believe your _content_ is protected - if you don't encrypt it, it will not be.

Comment: Depending on the protocol/implementation you use for your network communication it may be as easy configuring a proxy... if your implementation can't deal with proxies this might take some code-changes...

Comment: What would be a way that the server/client can find each other on the TOR network while still retaining privacy as to each other's location?

Comment: Maybe you meant onion routing? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onion_Routing

Comment: This might be of some use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962483/c-sharp-using-tor-as-proxy?rq=1

Comment: You'll need to configure a SOCKS proxy, and route all your traffic, including DNS lookups through it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the client has Privoxy installed then yes.

```
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:8118");  // Default port for privoxy
```

Those requests will then go through Tor.