# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8118

Tags: proxy, httpwebrequest, webrequest, tor

trying to create web request using Tor. getting this error - "Unable to connect to the remote server".
Tor default proxy - 8118.
i have goggled for it found solution for it   [using Tor as Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962483/c-sharp-using-tor-as-proxy)  but it didn't worked for me.

Code-

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Users\king\Downloads\Tor Browser\App\tor.exe", "ControlPort 9151 CircuitBuildTimeout 10");
p.Start();
Thread.Sleep(5000);
Regex regex = new Regex("\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}", RegexOptions.Multiline);

do
{       

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://whatismyipaddress.com/");
    request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
    request.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:8118");
    request.KeepAlive = false;

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")))
        {
            string contenu = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(regex.Match(contenu).Groups[0].Value);
        }
    }
    Console.Write("en attente : continuez ?");
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    if (line != "y")
        break;
}
while (true);

p.Kill();
Console.ReadLine();
```

any idea what doing wrong in above code.
thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tor default proxy port is 8118. you have to first download privoxy here

To chain Privoxy and Tor, both running on the same system, you would use something like:

```
    forward-socks5 / 127.0.0.1:9050
```

change its config to work with tor by uncommenting the above line

c# does not use sock proxies so that we have to run Tor and Provoxy at same. now you can send every web request using tor.

Answer (score 2):

Just download the Privoxy [here](http://www.privoxy.org/)

the reason to run tor through privoxy is because c# does not work with socks proxies. and tor is a socks proxy, so it needs to be ran through a html proxy that runs through tor